# How to Replace Words in all the Title Attributes using PHP

Tags: php, replace, attributes, character-replacement

I have search around and only found replacement options that were not specific to the need I have below.

However, the closest thing I found was this:

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)title="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','chocolate chip cookies',$items);
```

I think an answer to this question may also help others with similar needs.

Simply, I want to globally replace in one statement if possible, specific word(s) in all the title attributes (title="") with other word(s).
This should work for both hyperlink and image title attributes.

For example:
I would line to change the words "**chocolate**", "**chocolate cookies**", and "**chocolate vanilla cookies**" to "**chocolate chip cookies**" within all the title attributes as shown in the examples below.

However, I DO NOT want to change the word "**chocolate**" in either the URL or the link's text.

There are a total 50 items listings with 50 individual hyperlinks, all placed in a single array. So preferably, the replacement code should work for replacing the word(s) in the entire array in one statement.

**Note:** If Example 3 is too difficult, then an answer for Examples 1 and 2 will be sufficient.

Example 1:

```
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate">chocolate</a>
```

Example 2:

```
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate cookies">chocolate</a>
```

Example 3:

```
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate vanilla cookies">chocolate</a>
```

Desired Result:

```
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate chip cookies">chocolate</a>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with `getElementsByTagName`  to find the elements and test the value of the title attribute using a pattern:

```
\bchocolate(?:(?:\hvanilla)?\hcookies)?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `chocolate` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\hvanilla)?` Optionally match a horizontal whitespace char and *vanilla*
  - `\hcookies` Match a horizontal whitespace char and *cookies*
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4lM9d/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/QhXOv)

If the pattern matches, then you can set the new title.

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate">chocolate</a>
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate cookies">chocolate</a>
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate vanilla cookies">chocolate</a>
HTML;

$doc = new DomDocument();
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($html);
$doc->appendChild($fragment);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute(
        "title",
        preg_replace("~\bchocolate(?:(?:\hvanilla)?\hcookies)?\b~", "chocolate chip cookies", $node->getAttribute("title")
        )
    );
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate chip cookies">chocolate</a>
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate chip cookies">chocolate</a>
<a class="dessert" href="http://mywebsite.com/chocolate.php" title="Try out our new chocolate chip cookies">chocolate</a>
```

Comment: Thanks The fourth bird. I will take a look at this. Much appreciated for your help